# vector subscript out of range error strange behavior in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm starting to learn C++ so the answer to my question might be obvious to you but I am really puzzled. I expect the program would crash when accessing a out of range index but instead, the program runs just fine. Here is the code.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <typeinfo>
    #include <string>
    #include <vector>

    using namespace std;

    int main() {
        int x;
        vector<int> v1;

        while (cin >> x) {
            v1.push_back(x);
        }

        cout << "out of bound: " << v1[10] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And here is the output:

```
1 2 3
out of bound: 0
```

Comment: Googling hint: "Undefined behaviour."

Comment: That wasn't particularly hard to find btw. Please do more research the next time.

Comment: It's also helpful to read the documentation for [`operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) (and the method [`.at()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at))

Comment: Got it. Thank you everyone.

Comment: If you compile your program in debug mode, you usually get a diagnostic message if you access an out of bounds vector element.

Answer (score -3):

There are 3 elements in v1, meaning there is NO v1[10], only v1[0] through v1[2].

The behavior is not, strange. That’s what is supposed to happen, because std:: vector does not perform size checking for '[]'.

So, you are basically getting a garbage from v1[10].

Comment: OP is well aware there `v1[10]` is out of bounds and is *not* seeing an error. That's legal, but hardly *"what is supposed to happen"*.

Comment: I understand that there is no index v1[10] but shouldn't the program crash instead of returning 0 for non-exist index?

Comment: @ChrisN "_shouldn't the program crash instead of returning 0_" No, it shouldn't (it can, but that is not required), who told you, that it should?

Comment: @ChrisN no, it's not supposed to crash. The word "crash" doesn't even appear in the C++ standard

Comment: @Baum mit Augen, I clarified and edited. Thanks.

Comment: @Chris, please see the edited answer.

Comment: Thank you for your insights. However, if I define a vector<int> v1 without initializing it and try to access a non-exist index, the program will core dumped. I guess this has to do with 'Undefined behavior" vs something?

Comment: @ChrisN *undefined behavior* means that *anything* can happen. From core dumps to random values to demons jumping out of your nose - all of that is legal according to the language standard

Comment: @ChrisN "_I guess this has to do with 'Undefined behavior" vs something_" It is undefined behavior, as is the previous case. It may crash, or it may not - it's undefined.

Comment: That's still not particularly precise in terminology. If you choose to answer fairly obvious duplicates like that one, you better be prepared for your answers being held to the same standard as the common dupe target, which is often not trivial to meet.

Comment: @SajidHasanApon I'd recommend you take that answer off. You'll might even gain a badge for doing so.

Comment: @Baum mit Augen, I understand, and will be careful. Thanks. Also, I was not aware that the behavior is undefined because when I started learning STL, I too, experimented this way with various indices and did not get core dumped a single time. So, I just assumed that the value I got was from &the_vector+index*dataSize and will not get an error unless I point out of RAM.

Comment: Experiments are generally not a good way to learn C++.